# Calculating Canadian Tax in Shopping Cart, After Coupon Discount

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, laravel-4, shopping-cart

This is indeed a nightmare. I really need the help of your collective minds on this one:

In Canada, taxes are calculated differently from province to province:

```
Alberta - 5%
British Columbia - 5% GST and 7% PST
```

Calculating the straight tax on the price of each product is easy ... I loop over all of the items within the my cart and calculate the tax per the product price. Even when items are PST exempt, I can check for that...

The tricky part is when I have to apply a coupon code with a discount!

Obviously any discounts need to be applied to the pre-tax amounts... but I need to process each item separately to calculate the tax. I can't deduct say, $20 off of the cart total, because each item has it's own set price... which means while I'm processing each item, I need to know what the prices are AFTER the discount.

But remember how some products are PST exempt? Well, that weighs into the complication here:

```
Item 1 - $24.99 - GST (5%) and PST (7%)
Item 2 - $11.99 - GST (5%)

Discount - $20.00
```

How on earth can I apply the cart discount, but keep the integrity of the taxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do something like this (pseudocode)?

```
$item_price = $10
$final_price = ((($item_price * $discount) * $gst) * $pst)
```

then set discount to the inverse of 1.

i.e. no discount: `$discount = 1.0;`
20% discount: `$discount = .8;`

Edit: actually - you havent really given enough information. If the discount is a percentage of the total - then my code above will work.

But if your discount is a 'fixed' price - then you have a problem. Do you take the price off the first item, or distribute it to all items evenly across the cart? There will be tax implications either way.

Assuming you want to distribute the price across all items - then something like this would work:

```
$discount = $20;
$num_of_items_in_cart = 5;
$discount_per_item = $discount/$num_of_items_in_cart;
$final_price = ((($item_price * $discount_per_item) * $gst) * $pst)
```

Comment: Fixed price. "Do you take the price off the first item, or distribute it to all items evenly across the cart? There will be tax implications either way." That's exactly what I'm talking about...

Comment: Is there any reason why distributing the discount across all of the items wouldn't work? What if some items are GST and PST, while another is only PST?

Comment: My second code will solve the issue then. Just distrube the discount across all items. Alternatively - remove the discount from the first item. If they is a 'remainder' of discount, apply to second item and so on until $discount = 0;

Comment: It would work - personally that is how I would do it - just distribute across all items.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'll spend even more time programming that logic only to find out that the taxes are off. :/

Comment: One last question ... your logic here: ((($item_price * $discount_per_item) * $gst) * $pst) ... how does that account for a PST exempt (or QST in Quebec) item?

Comment: Because you would check before the item, something like (if 'pst' for this item = true) then '$pst = 7%' else '$pst = 0%. or something like that.

Comment: I guess the only other issue I'm afraid of is is you spread the discount out amongst the items, what if one of the items price is less than the divided discount portion? (Cart Total is $30. Item A is $20, Item B is $10, Discount is $15)

Comment: This is an interesting question it's a shame noboddy got a solution and documented it. I would like to re-open this question and solve it. Did you come to a solution?

Comment: lol after 7 years no body answered this. i am stuck in the same situation